# TimeoutException not being thrown Linq to SQL DataContext.CommandTimeout C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to throw a TimeoutException whenever it takes longer than 4 minutes to execute a stored procedure call in Linq to SQL.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Quality> Get(DateTime param1, DateTime param2, string param3)
        {     

            var dc = new VideoDataContext(WebApplication.MonitorServer);

            dc.CommandTimeout = 240;

            List<Quality> cqs = dc.Vid_GetQualityForVideo(param1, param2, 
            param3).ToList();


            return cqs;
        }
```

For some reason the code executes for longer (way longer) than 4 minutes but doesn't throw a timeout exception. In the end I get a Memory exception for really big queries.

I can't optimize the query or even see it because I don't have access to the stored procedures. I can only detect a timeout in the application. Does anyone know why I'm not getting a TimeoutException.

In other places in my code I have very similar code and the timeout is thrown after 4 minutes on another server holding a different database. It's just not happening here.

I can write to the Data team to change something in their but I'd like to be specific as to what the problem is.

Thanks!

Edit: To clarify I saw before when I retrieved data it would take forever and noticed that it was the massive amount of data being passed to the client. I have an MVC Action Filter that detects the number of rows and if it's more than a certain threshold (10000 right now) it only passes an error message to the client and not the entire dataset. The queries I'm running return way more than the threshold but it's still taking longer than 4 minutes to complete.

Comment: check connection string for `context connection`, is it set to true or false or not set at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is large the `.ToList()` may cause performance issues. The `IEnumerable<T>` you get from the query is *lazily* evaluated. However, calling a `.ToList()` will iterate through the entire contents of the result, putting it into the resulting `List` (`cqs`).

If you truly wish the return of your function to be `IEnumerable<Quality>` then you may be able to just return the query `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable<Quality> Get(DateTime param1, DateTime param2, string param3)
    {     

        var dc = new VideoDataContext(WebApplication.MonitorServer);

        dc.CommandTimeout = 240;

        return dc.Vid_GetQualityForVideo(param1, param2, param3);
    }
```

Edit:

To clarify, if you are getting a memory flow, not a timeout flow, I would suspect that evaluating the IEnumerable into `cqs` is filling memory as quickly as the `IEnumerable` iterates. I would use LINQ queries (`Filter`, etc.) to truncate the resulting `IEnumerable`.

Also (reminded in comments), I'll put my money on the reason you are not getting a timeout is because `dc.Vid_GetQualityForVideo(param1, param2, param3)` evaluates successfully. The following `ToList()` called upon it returning is causing the overflow. Doing some basic breakpoints checks on it would confirm this.

Comment: Also, if resultset is too big, then i believe it won't be a TimeOut case while large data retrieving is still in progress...

Comment: Forgot that part, adding clarification to answer.

Comment: It's around 500,000 rows and each row has about 20-30 columns so it is pretty massive.

Comment: You could do some napkin maths on how much work `ToList` must do and calculate the size of each element multiplied by the expected return value. Might turn out that the number is *very* large. However, for your current issue I'd just recommend the breakpoint testing.

Comment: Let's say I pass two dates only a couple of days apart, it will take 6.5 minutes from SSMS and 6.5 minutes to return the list to the client. I'm also iterating through the IEnumerable to get the count of the records. Would this eagerly retrieve the data?

Comment: It would depend entirely on the implementation of `VideoDataContext`. For all I know, it is eagerly retrieving all 500k records and performing date filtrations client-side.

Comment: They changed the requirements so I don't have to implement this but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably request worked well and your large data being received via network. In this case no TimeOut exception should occur.

Comment: Good point! I noticed that and I don't return all the data to the client if it's more than a certain number of rows (10000). Right now the queries return way more than 10000.

Comment: if exactly this was an issue then i'd be glad to see the answer accepted :) otherwise please don't

Comment: That was the issue before I asked this question but I fixed it and I'm still not getting the timeout from server side

Comment: can you run the query in SSMS and check time it runs before 1st record gets retrieved?

Comment: It's like 5 seconds before it starts returning rows and like 6.5 minutes for the query to finish entirely

Comment: The timeout property only applies to how long ADO will wait for data to *start* returning